# Deploy Watson AI (with option response function) in Node-RED

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, watson-assistant

I'm using watson assistant were i have created a skill and in that i have used "option response". so i am deploying it in node-RED.

[image]

The problem is that in UI when watson interact with user upto when its not came up with "option response" but when watson has to response with option functionality  then it's not showing any option!

[image]

as you can see here watson asked for email address and then next watson reply has to be in "option response" but its not showing.....

in function 1 node code is :-

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.text;
return msg;
```

in function 2 node code is :-

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.output.text[0];
return msg;
```

in form node :-

[image]

I tried to explain my problem as clear as I can. please! please! help me out with that.
if I have used less nodes or whatever it is please let me know.

I want to show what output watson has to show :

[image]

when I tried typing this code in function node 2 :

```
msg.payload =payload
```

then in debug node at that point where watson has to option response is like that :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstand you, but I believe you are trying to output into your bot response the options that Watson Assistant responds with. If this is the case you need to look at the JSON payload that is returned from Watson, as displayed in the debug node. Your function 2 is only returning the text response from assistant. The option responses are within a different part of the json payload, i.e.
msg.payload = msg.payload.output.generic[0].options[0].label

Comment: The comments I made yesterday were to help guide you towards where to look within the json payload for the options information, i.e. label and value. Normally the application UI code would need to transform the Watson Assistant response into the correct format for your UI. As chughts points out we do not know which UI nodes you are using. However most will take html code. Thus you need within your function code to take the Watson response and convert it to html ( again this is a guess).

Answer (score 0):

timd’s answer is actually correct. If you send only the text to the bot node, it will only display the test.

You need to check what format the bot node you are using expects payload to be in, and whether it can cope with options, and how it expects options to look like.

In your function node you will need to transform the output from the Assistant node into the expected input for the bot node.

Without knowing what bot node you are using and the input format it expects it is very difficult to go into more specifics, other than you are sending the wrong data.